# Optimizing the download speed using java

Tags: java, performance, download

Hi I am working on a download tool and i found that the downloading speed is too low. I hav e checked the download speed looks slow. My code is as follows,

```
        float fileSize = Float.parseFloat(uc.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));

        in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("File size : " + fileSize);


        fout = new FileOutputStream(settingsForm.downloadDirectoryText.getText() + File.separatorChar + fileName);
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int count = 0;
        int totalDownloaded = 0;

        long downloadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long remainingTime = 0;



        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {

            totalDownloaded += count;
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - downloadStartTime;

            float speedInBytes = 1000f * totalDownloaded / elapsedTime;
            float tmpSpeed = speedInBytes;
            if (tmpSpeed > 1024) {
                tmpSpeed = tmpSpeed / 1024;
            }
            if (tmpSpeed > 1024 * 1024) {
                tmpSpeed = tmpSpeed / (1024 * 1024);
            }
            System.out.println("Speed : " + tmpSpeed);
            System.out.println("Remaining Time : " + (fileSize - totalDownloaded) / speedInBytes + " seconds");
            int downloadPercentage = (int) ((totalDownloaded / fileSize) * 100);

            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

I found that the download took 90seconds with an average download speed as 60-70kbps.

I have given the download link to a [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) which is downloading the same file within 10seconds. It can able to download the same file with a download speed of more 400kpbs.

Why can't I able to download with the much speed ?

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FDM uses many connections, that each download a part of the file. You could try to implement that.

Comment: Can you try by reducing number of writes to outputstream? Dont use fout.write(data, 0, count); in every loop iteration. Use a bigger buffer and write once after say 10 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without modification your code should run a lot faster than 60 KB/s. You can add a BufferedWriter but the difference is negligible. You use the faster method to copy : read/write with a byte buffer. BufferedReader add speed when you use the read() method (which reads character per character). However the size of the buffer can improve the process, I have good results with 64 * 1024.

You can also remove your if (tmpSpeed > 1024 ... and replace with (no 'if' is needed here)  :

```
double tmpSpeed = speedInBytes / 1024;
```

I have tested our program on my machine from one HD to another and I got the following speed with a file of 1GB :

```
21057ms
49797 KB/s  >>> 60 KB/s
```

It is not your code the problem, the slowness come from the network. Try with different files from different servers, etc ...